# How to get Modx to retrieve data about an object the current user does not have access to?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm trying to retrieve a preview [thumbnail Template Variable] of a resource that a user doe not have access to [a teaser preview]
The problem is that if I try to create a modResource object from the resource id I have [and the current user does not have access to that resource] the resource object is not created.

i.e. $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $id); fails.

Is there a way/method of using getObject so that it will ignore Modx permissions?

Comment: Try add permissions "load,list,view" to user.

Comment: That would circumvent other extras that should be respecting permissions. i.e. wayfinder, getResources etc. [generally anything that requests some or part of a resource.]

Comment: I may be mistaken, but $modx->getObject didnt check any permissions, if it fails - maybe resource doesnt exist?

Comment: I would have sworn that up and down a couple of days ago myself, now I'm not so sure.